# SQL statement can be outputted in rails console but not in view (rails 6)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to display an output from this rails command " Userlist.order(:role)" from a userlist table I had

and it has a valid output from the console but when it add it in my controller like @userrole = Userlist.order(:role)

it outputted a bunch of hash like this Userlist:0x0000000008c10978

Therefore how i do configure the command at my controller i had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add `.inspect` method to the `@userrole`. But output still will be ugly

Comment: Like this?  @userrole=Userlist.order(:role).inspect

Comment: Better to do it in your view template like `<%= @userrole.inspect %>`